# Difference between double and Double Visual C++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, types, double, type-conversion

What is the difference between the types ***double*** and ***Double*** in managed C++? Is it value (i.e size range) related or simply a modernized type to suit the Net Framework?

From what I understand, Double comes from System::Double and is in itself a value class and can behave as an object if required and not just a value unlike it's ISO/IEC predecessor. But for instance, if I was parsing a float to double, why would I use this:

```
Console::Write(L"Enter a value: ");
float value = Double::Parse(Console::ReadLine());                        
Console::WriteLine(L"You entered {0}", value);
```

instead of:

```
Console::Write(L"Enter a value: ");
float value = double::Parse(Console::ReadLine());                        
Console::WriteLine(L"You entered {0}", value);
```

I understand I am sort of asking two questions in one with the parsing but it would help me understand double from Double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing they are synonyous, same as `int`/`Int32`, `string`/`String`. In terms of usage, I tend to use the Pascal casing when accessing static methods (like Parse) and the lowercase for declaring variables - just my preference though.

FYI - in your example you aren't parsing a `float` to a `double` your parsing a `string` to a `double` and assigning it to a `float` variable. You may encounter precision issues by doing that, if your parsing a `double` then your variable should be of type `double`. If you do need to parse a float use [Single::Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2thct5cb.aspx) instead.

Comment: Thanks. So it would be double value = Double::Parse() ?

Comment: @wilbomc Yep, or you can use 'auto' keyword which is the equivalent to the var keyword in C#. It just means you don't need to define the variable type it's implied by the value being assigned e.g. auto value = Double::Parse